# sass import file missing from yeoman app

Tags: yeoman-generator-angular

I imported the sass files in my main.scss b/w

```
// bower:scss
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
@import "custom/app.scss";
// endbower
```

Whenever  there is a style change or my app is getting restarted the imported scss files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The generator probably has generated a gulp/gruntfile that uses something like [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) to try find references (in this case, SCSS files) and inject them between the two 'magical' comments. The only references it will find are for components that are installed through [Bower](http://bower.io/). But it will first throw away anything that it considers obsolete (it assumes you have removed the Bower component and since it can not find it).

To fix this, just declare your @imports after the magic comments.

As a side note, it is good practice to use Bower to install components such as Bootstrap. Will make updating them and integrating them into the build process a bit easier.

(I hope this answered your question - I did make a few assumptions: I'm assuming that the files aren't get removed but the @import statements are. If the actual SCSS files are removed, as could be interpreted from the question, then this answer is not valid).